# Storm Emit Execute Latency

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have a Storm topology running in a distributed environment across 4 Unix nodes.

I have a JMSSpout that receives a message and then forwards it onto a ParseBolt that will parse the raw message and create an object.

To help measure latency my JMSSpout emits the current time as a value and then when the ParseBolt receives this it will get the current time again and take the difference as the latency.

Using this approach I am seeing 200+ ms which doesn't sound right at all. Does anyone have an idea with regards to why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a threading issue.  Storm uses the same thread for all spout nextTuple() calls and tuples emitted aren't processed until the nextTuple() call ends.  There's also a very tight loop that repeatedly calls the nextTuple() method and it can consume a lot of cycles if you don't put at least a short sleep in the nextTuple() implementation.

Try adding a sleep(10) and emitting only one tuple per nextTuple().

Comment: Ah this makes sense. I am doing some parsing in the bolt and I am thinking that the nextTuple() call is taking a while to finish so my tuples are getting backed up behind the scenes (And adding additional latency).

Comment: Tested my Bolt by removing the parsing logic and its much faster now. However, if I am unable to improve the parsing function then what else can I do to improve efficiency? I found a thread with Nathan M talking about making a spout multi-threaded to speed up the nextTuple() process. (By the way, adding the sleep function in also saved me 10ms so thanks for that).

Comment: If this is the intermediate bolt (the parsing bolt), why not increase the parallelism hint to make more instances?  I assume you're not maxing CPU out right now on the nodes.

Comment: I increased the parallelism hint to 4 for this particular bolt and we see a dramatic performance increase. Thanks for that suggestion.